# Fabricjs flipping canvas changes position

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to flip (mirror) my canvas if I press on a button, the first mirror works but if I try to click again it does not revert properly and the position of the drawn canvas is wrong it is top left.

```
    $('#btnMirrorImage.')click(() => {
        let objs = canvas.getObjects().map((o) => {
            return o.set('active', true);
        });
        let group = new fabric.Group(objs, {
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center'
        });
        canvas._activeObject = null;
        // if it is already mirrored revert it
        if(this.elements.isMirrored) {
            canvas.setActiveGroup(group.setCoords().set("angle", "180").set('flipY', true));
            this.elements.isMirrored = false;
        }
        // else try to mirror it -> works 
        else {
            canvas.setActiveGroup(group.setCoords().set("angle", "-180").set('flipY', true));
            this.elements.isMirrored = true;
        }
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
```

Currently I click on the button the drawn canvas gets mirrored/flipped and if I click on the button again it does not get reverted.

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML and the JS which references the canvas?